# Treeshaking when importing images, and wanting to use Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tree-shaking

I have a component that looks like this:

```
import foo from "./assets/foo.svg"; 
import bar from "./assets/bar.svg"; 

const icons = {foo, bar}; 

type IconTypes = "foo" | "bar"; 

type IconProps = {
    icon: IconTypes; 
}; 


export const Icon = (props: IconProps) => {
    const IconComp = icons[props.icon]; 
    return <IconComp/> 
}
```

Now, as I understand it, this doesn't treeshake properly.

That is, if I have something like

```
<App> 
    <Icon icon = "foo"/> 
</App>
```

Then this will be bundled with all of the SVGs.

I could just reference the Icons directly:

```
import FooIcon from "./assets/foo.svg"; 
<App> 
    <FooIcon/> 
</App>
```

But where I don't to do this, is that I might have multiple other components that optionally display an icon, eg, a button with an icon, or a card with an icon etc.

I would rather be using these components like

```
<Button icon = "foo" /> 
<Card icon = "foo"/>
```

And have this immediately give me type errors if I've made a typo on the icon name.

The alternative is to pass in the icon like:

```
import FooIcon from "./assets/foo.svg"; 
<Button Icon = {FooIcon}/> 
<Card Icon = {FooIcon}/>
```

But I really don't like this.

Is there a way to achieve this, or am I misunderstanding the tree shaking here?

Answer (score 2):

How about using dynamic imports from Webpack? Would this be something you could use in your context? If configured properly, it could generate a different chunk for each `.svg` and only be downloaded when used. https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1

**Edit**
Another option could be to pass the actual SVG import directly as a prop to your Icon component, like that, the SVGs would only be in chunks where they are used. You would have to change your props for Icon to accept an Object.

Comment: Yup, this could be a good solution, although then the downside would be that now you have deal with async components and the icons appearing after page load. 

Really I guess I'm looking for also a way to create components (ie. the component can assume that the the'icon' value isn't going to change.

Comment: How about this solution? (Edited)